# Symmetric Matrices Sign of pivots

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It is said that symmetric matrices have equal number of positive eigen values as that of positive pivots.
But when finding the reduced row echelon form, we are free to multiply a row by a scalar quantity, so wouldn't we be able to change the sign (e.g. $r_1\longmapsto -r_1$)?

Comment: I think this is under the assumption that you don't rescale rows. (You really do not need to rescale rows anyway, so this is a reasonable assumption.)

Comment: Rescale in the sense..multiply by a scalar once we have already got the rref of the matrix?Won't doing row reduction in various methods...sometimes result in a row which is negative of the same when done using another method?

Comment: Being clear, you don't need to actually modify any rows by multiplying them by scalars. You can instead multiply them in a temporary variable, then add them to another row, and leave the row you started with as it was. If you do your row reduction this way, then the pivots will tell you the signs of the eigenvalues (in the symmetric case). If you change rows by rescaling them, then it will not work. (Simple example: think about changing the sign of the first row of the identity matrix. This is a valid row operation, but it obviously changes the sign of an eigenvalue.)

Comment: An example: you are reducing $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 9 \end{bmatrix}$, then you multiply the first row by $-2$ and add it to the second row, but without actually changing the first row, so that your matrix at the next stage is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, *not* $\begin{bmatrix} -4 & -8 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: In other words..we are  allowed to Rx=k(Rx)-Ry in general during row reduction..but if we want the pivots to tell us the sign..we need to make sure k is 1?

Comment: $k$ just has to be positive.

Comment: Where is this said, exactly?  Maybe if you name the text, we can figure out what the author meant.

Comment: Linear algebra by gilbert strang. The chapter on symmetric matrices!

Comment: @Sridhar Thiagarjan :what about interchanging the rows? Do you thi k is this a valid row operation in order to obtain pivots for row echleon form?Take example A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} when you interchange Row 1 by row 2 you get identity matrix which has both eige values positive but the original matrix has eigen values +1 and -1